# Whe aren't my subpages visible with nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am making simple node app for my website.
I've configured my `app.js`, controllers and routers so far.
My problem is I keep getting error 404 on two from three subpages, index works fine also. I think they're pretty much the same construction-wise, I've tried tracing app-route-controller but seems good to me.

My console output:

```js
GET / 304 1.443 ms - -
GET /css/style.css 304 0.325 ms - -
GET /images/IMG_2202.png 304 0.639 ms - -
GET /images/vertabelo-tabele.png 304 0.774 ms - -

GET /sprzet 200 1.904 ms - 3241
GET /css/style.css 304 0.393 ms - -
GET /images/IMG_2202.png 304 0.501 ms - -

GET /zamowienia 404 1.152 ms - 1393

GET /wysylka 404 0.917 ms - 1393
```

As you can see `/zamowienia` and `/wysylka` are not found. However the structure is the same as for sprzet.

My app.js

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const sprzetRouter = require('./routes/sprzetRoute');
const wysylkaRouter = require('./routes/wysylkaRoute');
const zamowieniaRouter = require('./routes/zamowieniaRoute');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/sprzet', sprzetRouter);
app.use('/list-wys', wysylkaRouter);
app.use('/list', zamowieniaRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

wysylkaRoute

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const wysylkaController = require('../controllers/wysylkaController');

router.get('/', wysylkaController.showWysylkaList);
router.get('/add', wysylkaController.showAddWysylkaForm);
router.get('/details/:wysId', wysylkaController.showWysylkaDetails);

module.exports = router;
```

and wysylkaController

```js
const { Router } = require("express");

exports.showWysylkaList = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('pages/wysylka/list-wys', {
        navLocation: 'wys'
    });
}

exports.showAddWysylkaForm = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('pages/wysylka/form-wys', {
        navLocation: 'wys'
    });
}

exports.showWysylkaDetails = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('pages/wysylka/list-wys-details', {
        navLocation: 'wys'
    });
}
```

My `nav` also seems fine:

```html
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="/" class="<%= navLocation == 'main' ? 'active' : ''%>">Strona główna</a></li>
<li><a href="/zamowienia" class="<%= navLocation == 'zam' ? 'active' : ''%>">Zamówienia</a></li>
<li><a href="/sprzet" class="<%= navLocation == 'sprz' ? 'active' : ''%>">Sprzęt</a></li>
<li><a href="/wysylka" class="<%= navLocation == 'wys' ? 'active' : ''%>">Wysylka</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I've tried backtracing all my paths and comparing `/wysylka` and `/zamowienia` to `/sprzet` but they all seem built the same way.

Comment: You sure the anchor tags are linked to the right path? I see a few differences. For example `wysylka` isn't specified anywhere.

Comment: @mode_modules Do you mean anchor tags in the `<nav>`?

Comment: Yes, I meant those :) @Linlee

Comment: @mode_modules I mean, they're all pointing to regarding sub folders. `views/pages` and there you have `/sprzet`, `/wysylka`, `/zamowienia`. I might be blind at this point, since I'm looking for it since monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were wrong endpoints in the `app.js`.

I had to switch this:

```js
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/sprzet', sprzetRouter);
app.use('/list-wys', wysylkaRouter);
app.use('/list', zamowieniaRouter);
```

To this:

```js
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/sprzet', sprzetRouter);
app.use('/wysylka', wysylkaRouter);
app.use('/zamowienia', zamowieniaRouter);
```

For endpoints to point to the subfolders instead of specific files.